# how to copy database to a new database other then creating backup and restoring it

Tags: sql-server

How can i copy complete database to a new database ?

1. Can i do it only through creating backup and restoring in new name?
   or 
   is their any other way of doing it.

Please let me know if any other way of doing it.

Comment: Backup and restore isn't the only way but it's by far the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Import Export Wizard to copy all tables and views etc.

I think you need to create an empty database first, then copy the tables and data across

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Detach the database, copy and rename the MDF and LDF files, attach both again
Backup/restore is by far the easiest way

For small databases, you can use the SSMS wizards